Socketio Postman Python not displaying emet
the code I'm using
enter image description here
import socketio
from aiohttp import web

# Создаем экземпляр сервера Socket.IO
sio = socketio.AsyncServer(async_mode='aiohttp')

# Создаем aiohttp веб-приложение и связываем его с Socket.IO
app = web.Application()
sio.attach(app)

# Обработчик события подключения
@sio.event
async def connect(sid, environ):
    print(f"Клиент {sid} подключен")
    await sio.emit('users', data={'content': 'welcome'}, room=sid)

# Обработчик события отключения
@sio.event
async def disconnect(sid):
    print(f"Клиент {sid} отключен")

@sio.on("message")
async def incoming_message(sid, data):
    print("мне сказали", data, sid)
    await sio.emit('users', to=sid, data={'content': 'welcome'}, room=sid)

# Запускаем aiohttp веб-сервер
if __name__ == '__main__':
    web.run_app(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8001)

why the line
" await sio.emit('users', data={'content': 'welcome'}, room=sid) " "
as I understand on the postman where the black arrow on the photo is indicated {'content':   '     welcome'} should be displayed why it doesn't happen
help me please
It doesn't show any errors,
